# Why many methods in JCF interfaces not made default in Java 8?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, default-method

Minimum complete definition of `Collection` interface consists only of two methods: `iterator()` and `size()`, which are abstract in `AbstractCollection`.

Why all other methods not made default in Java 8? Compatibility shouldn't be an issue, for example, `Iterator.remove()` was abstract until Java 7, but made default since Java 8.

Subclassing from `AbstractCollection` is inconvenient sometimes, when I want a `Collection` implementation to be a member of another class hierarchy. Wasn't that one of the reasons why default methods in interfaces actually needed in Java?

The same question about `Map`, `List` and other basic interfaces, comprising Java Collection Framework.

**UPDATE**

Paul Sandoz:

> Generally we have only converted existing abstract methods on an interface to non-abstract if there was a compelling reason to aid implementations, such as Iterator.remove.
>
> These are not new methods on Collection, and there are already implementations in AbstractCollection. The advantage of converting these abstract into non-abstract methods its not particularly compelling given one is most likely to inherit from AbstractCollection or provide more efficient implementations.
>
> It would be possible to move all non-abstract methods on AbstractCollection to Collection. If we were starting from a blank sheet of paper that is what we might have done. (Note one cannot do this with all non-abstract methods on AbstractList.)

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2014-February/025118.html

Comment: Questions like _Why was X implemented in this way?_ is seldom a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Keppil it is nonsense. I can link 10 ultra high-voted SO questions, formulated the same way, and with approximately similar discourse, in 10 minutes.

Comment: @Keppil simply google "why java site:stackoverflow.com"

Comment: I think that between 7 and 8 will not be incompatible in contract classes i.e. Collection, ArrayList, LinkedList etc. But in AbstractCollection they can make changes because it is not "contract list" it is for their use.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan I doubt. What is different from `Iterator.remove()`?

Comment: `Iterator.remove()` is different for each collection. In some classes it doesn't implemented and throws something like `nonImplementedException`

Comment: No, it is not default for `Collection` interface, it is default for `Iterator` interface which `Collection` interface inherits. but other classes too can implement `Iterator` interface. For example `Scanner` class implements `Iterator` interface, but doesn't implement `remove` method and throw `UnsupportedOperationException` exception.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan You confuse `Iterator` and `Iterable`.

Comment: So `iterable` contains `Iterator` inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary goal of default methods is to enable compatible evolution of interfaces. See section 10 of the [State of the Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html) document. One of the main directions of this evolution is to facilitate internal iteration. See the *Internal vs External Iteration* section of [State of the Lambda: Libraries Edition](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-libraries-final.html). To this end, there are new methods such as `Iterable.forEach`, `Collection.removeIf`, and `List.replaceAll`.

Other methods like `List.sort` have been added because it allows individual concrete list implementations to provide more efficient sorting algorithms, which cannot be done with `Collections.sort`.

Finally, default methods have been added for sheer convenience, such as `Iterator.remove`. Over the years, we and many others have gotten quite annoyed at adding a method `remove` that simply throws `UnsupportedOperationException` every time we implemented a new `Iterator`. The default method `remove` does this for us. Note, crucially, that this method doesn't actually remove any elements. (How would it?)

It might seem convenient to provide default implementations for a bunch of `Collection` methods, written in terms of other methods such as `iterator`. However, I don't think it's very useful, and in fact I'm not sure it's even possible for some methods.

Consider the `Collection.contains(Object)` method. It's conceivable that one could write a default implementation of this in terms of `iterator` by stepping through each element and comparing for equality. This would be a very bad implementation for something like a `TreeSet` or a `HashSet`. Even the concrete `List` implementations such as `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` provide fast-path implementations that are much more efficient than stepping through an iterator. Having a default implementation of `Collection.contains` might be a little bit convenient, but really, it doesn't add much value. In practice every collection will want to override it.

Now consider `equals`. The [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) of `Collection.equals` raises a bunch of subtle issues. Briefly, a `Set` can only be equal to another `Set`, and a `List` can only be equal to another `List`, and the `equals` operation must be symmetric. It follows that a `Collection` that's neither a `List` nor a `Set` can never be equal to a `List` or a `Set`.

OK, so our `Collection.equals` default method will have to do a bunch of `instanceof` checks up front. If both are `Lists` we can delegate to `AbstractList.equals`, and if both are `Sets` we can delegate to `AbstractSet.equals`. Now let's suppose that this object and the other object neither `Lists` nor `Sets`. What if they are different concrete implementations that cannot be equal to each other? We can't tell.

Setting that aside, let's assume that we equality is defined as having the same membership. The only thing we can do is to iterate through each collection. But we can't (in general) make any assumptions about iteration order, so we can't iterate through them simultaneously and compare elements pairwise like we would for lists. Instead, we'd have to load all the elements from one collection into a temporary collection of some kind. It can't be a `Set` since we might have duplicates. We'd then check each element of the other `Collection` to make sure that every element in it is in the first one, and that there are no extras in the first one. This isn't terribly difficult, but it's expensive, and some semantics such as order sensitivity are not supported.

I can't imagine any concrete collection subclass actually wanting to use this algorithm.

---

In summary, using default methods to make collection implementations easier is not one of the design goals of default methods. In addition, while it might seem that providing default methods on `Collection` would be convenient, they don't actually seem useful. Any reasonable `Collection` implementation will need to override all the methods in order to provide the semantics it wants without being horribly inefficient.

Comment: The same reasoning could be applied to `AbstractCollection`. Is this class useful, while any reasonable concrete implementation will need to override most of the methods. Adhoc collections are usually written for adhoc use, when only a few of `Collection` methods are used, the rest could be left arbitrarily inefficient.

Comment: There is at least one method, very similar to `Iterator.remove()`. Over the years developers bothered to implement `isEmpty()` as `return size() == 0;`...

Comment: One more thing: most of concrete collections from `java.util` *does not* override methods like `retainAll`, `removeAll`, `containsAll`, `equals` and `hashCode`, they inherit implementetations from `AbstractCollection`, `AbstractList` or `AbstractSet`.

Comment: The original question was whether a complete `Collection` implementation (except for `iterator` and `size`) could be provided by default methods. This could be attempted but it isn't really feasible, as I described. Note that `equals` and `hashCode` are also abstract in `AbstractCollection` for the same reasons. The situation with `AbstractCollection` isn't the same, as it doesn't purport to provide a complete implementation. It relies on careful inheritance and overriding from `AbstractList` and `AbstractSet`.

Comment: As Paul Sandoz said, if we were starting over we might consider putting more implementations into default methods on Collection/List/Set, but this could be problematic. Interfaces cannot have state (though the Abstract* classes don't have any); nor can interfaces define protected or private interfaces, which are used in the abstract classes. Bottom line is that interfaces and default methods don't provide mixins, and this wasn't the design goal of default methods anyway.

Comment: Regarding `isEmpty()` default. Using `size()` is a poor default since some `size()` implementations are O(n) or in a few cases, uncountable. `isEmpty()` is generally expected to be O(1). We chose not to provide all possible defaults just those that were very commonly useful or required.

Comment: @mduigou, Stuart Marks, Alhough I would like Collection methods to be made default in Java 8, you indeed answered to my question *why* they weren't. Thanks for attention.